# Get the value of integer after animation JAVA

Tags: java, animation

I've been given a project that uses animations for calculations, the issue is that i'm interested in the values that are obtained after the animation has ended, but I try to read the values it will read the whole set of values that the animation uses while getting there, how could I capture the values that are displayed after the end of the animation.

```
  @Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {

    super.paint(g);

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    FontMetrics metrics = g2.getFontMetrics();
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    String labelText = getLabelText();
    g2.setColor(getForeground());
    g2.drawString(labelText, 0, getHeight() / 2 - metrics.getHeight() / 2 + metrics.getAscent());

    int strWidth = metrics.stringWidth(labelText);
    int barWidth = getWidth() - strWidth - 11;
    int barHeight = 10;
    g2.setColor(new Color(ColorUtils.getColor(Const.COLOR_RED, Const.COLOR_GREEN, currValue)));
    g2.fillRect(strWidth + 10, getHeight() / 2 - barHeight / 2, (int)(barWidth * currValue), barHeight);
    a++;
}

private String getLabelText() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(name);
    builder.append(" - ");
    String percentage = String.format("%.2f%%", currValue * 100f);
    //I would like to obtain this value after the animation is over.
    double valor = currValue * 100f;


    for(int i = 0; i < 7 - percentage.length(); i++) {
        builder.append(" ");
    }
    builder.append(percentage);

    return builder.toString();
}

@Override
public void animate(long deltaMs) {
    long animDuration = Const.ANIM_DURATION_SHORT;
    if(currentTime < animDuration) {
        currentTime += deltaMs;
        if(currentTime > animDuration) {
            currentTime = animDuration;
        }
        currValue = initValue + ((float) currentTime / animDuration) * (destValue - initValue);
        if(currValue > 1.0f) {
            currValue = 1.0f;
        }
        if(currValue < 0.0f) {
            currValue = 0.0f;
        }
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean `currValue`? It seems that is already a field on this component, so what is your difficulty accessing it?

Comment: After I read the code now a little bit I understand how the animation worked, and I think I found my solution, yeah currValue cant be accesed but for example if I wanted to print currValue I would have to print it like 300 times because that's the amount of times the animation would run after finally printing the last value which is the one I want.

Comment: wait for the end of the animation (we don't have the code for that) and then read the value... or, add an `else` block to the `if` statement in `animate` method that *saves* (or prints) the value